# Write a function receives two arguments and returns the difference

Tags: c

Write a C-program that calls a function minus(). This function receives two arguments and returns the difference (regular subtraction, not absolute). This difference should be printed on screen.

My code is:

```
int minus(int a,int b)
{
    int c = a - b;
    return c;
}
int main()
{
    int a = 4; int b = 5;
    minus(a,b);
    printf("%d", minus);
    return 0;
}
```

I have two questions:

1.why a and b in

```
int minus(int a,int b)
```

are grey in Visual Studio? "int" is blue but a and b are grey.
[image]
2. I got this result but it should be -1.

[image]

Could someone help me please

Comment: Coloring is for the keyword `int`.

Comment: What according to you `printf("%d", minus);` does???

Comment: You priting the adress of `minus`. And you have to write `printf(..., minus(a, b))`.

Comment: What you really need is a tutorial in C. Or at least read whatever material you have for whatever kind of class/course/lecture you are taking. There should have been a chapter on calling functions recently. You seem to have skipped that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an assignment

```
int minus(int a,int b)
{
    int c = a - b;
    return c;
}
int main()
{
    int a = 4; int b = 5;
    int d = minus(a,b);
    printf("%d", d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the typeo in the variable declaration, made the correction

Comment: I considered `d` better, in order to minimise possible confusion.

Comment: Make sense, updated accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behavior here printing the function pointer using `%d` format specifier. (You have used the wrong format specifier that's why the Undefined behavior).

And the most probable way you would like is to `printf("%d", minus(a,b));`. You wanted to print the result of the subtraction not the function pointer itself.

Comment: @EOF.: Nope you can't do that. I edited. There is a way to print fucntion pointer which is supposedly to using a `unsigned char*` and print byte by byte. I guess I would take the day off....

Comment: @EOF: Technically, that is in C 2011 clause 4, paragraph 6: “A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly conforming program.” :-) Which would make this a conforming program by paragraph 7. So it is “allowed,” just not “defined.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil.: Thanks for the explanation reference.

Answer (score 1):

1. `a` and `b` are grey because the editor is automatically coloring the code to help illustrate the program syntax. This may look funny at first, but, over time, your brain will become accustomed to it, and things that are the wrong colors will stand out. This will help you find mistakes in your program—when you make a mistake typing, something that should be a keyword will be colored like a parameter name, and you may notice it is the wrong color and take a closer look at what you typed.
2. In `printf("%d", minus);`, the `minus` is just the function. It is not the value returned by the function. To print the value returned by the function, use `printf("%d", minus(a, b));`.

Comment: "int" is blue but a and b are grey" – OP doesn't seem to know the difference between types and variables. I find the fact that `a` and `b` are grey but `c` is *black* much more interesting. As you say, it is designed to help the (not-totally n00b) programmer. Now that *is* a pretty useful function!

Answer (score -2):

you called the function minus() but you did not take the value returned by function in any variable so when you try to print minus then it will return the pointer value of function. so to get the correct answer hold the return value in variable and then print it         `int c = minus(a,b);
    printf("%d", c);` or you can call the minus function inside the print function like this `printf("%d", minus());` as a beginner i will suggest you to implement the first suggestion it will increase the capacity to use statements in c.